# How to transform Modellica code to Ontologies (.owl)?

Tags: java, binary-tree, semantic-web, owl, dymola

I working on a mechatronic project and i use dymola tool to generate modelica code for my model . now i want to transform modellica to .owl inorder to implement semantic search for the elements . I used protege to manually generate ontologies but its time consuming . i need  to design a tool that automatically does that for me  . the tool can be programmed in Java but the problem is how to make the tool understand the semantics ( not just the syntactic structure) of d modellica code ? if grammar parsing is the answer, how? or is there any alternate way other than using a parser?
can sum1 help me! ...it would be great if u could refer me some books that can go thro ..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please show us your code.

Comment: I have a task on hand where I have to build a RDF/OWL ontology from Modelica classes, and stumbled across your question while searching online. I am curious if you found a way to expedite this tedious process.

Answer (score 0):

The [OWL-API](http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/) is a solid Java library to work with OWL. It's the engine behind Protege so you might want to start looking there. You could also try [Brain](http://loopasam.github.com/Brain/), it supports only the [OWL2 EL](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-profiles/#OWL_2_EL)
profile at the moment.